# Access data received by the HTTPs endpoint by my java console app

Tags: java, json, mongodb, webhooks, mongodb-java

I'm using mongoDB to store and read data from my Java application. My application, in addition to working with the MongoDB database, works with an API for sending messages via whatsapp. Everything is working so far, but I need to get the "webhook" sent by this external service, I managed to configure an HTTPS Endpoint in Realm, I would like to know if it is possible to read this data through my Java console application. I tried to synchronize the Realm with the database but I was unsuccessful, the idea was to record the data received by the HTTPS endpoint in a collection and access it through my Java application.

Thanks to everyone who can contribute with any suggestions.

Comment: Hey Vitor! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you improve your question with example, error or similar output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.